# Modify "LocalizedName" for an Business-process-flow in Dynamics 365 (Version 9.0)

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need to unify the "display name" of an business-process-flow in our environment.

The standard BPF "Opportunity Sales Process", should be called "Opportunity Sales Process" regardless of the UI language of the use (e.g. "Vertriebsprozess Verkaufschance" is the "LocalizedName" for German users).

I have not found any way to change the "LocalizedName" value - the only option is see, is the direct update of the customizations.xml.

Is is possible to update the "LocalizedName" of an BPF via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IOrganizationService os; // todo - initialize
```

Its not clear what you're after :) If you're after updating entity metadata - that is doable:

```
var request = new RetrieveEntityRequest { LogicalName = "opportunitysalesprocess" };
var response = (RetrieveEntityResponse)os.Execute(request);
var label = response.EntityMetadata.DisplayName.LocalizedLabels
  .First(l => l.LanguageCode == 1033);
label.Label = "Thats Not My Name";
os.Execute(new UpdateEntityRequest { Entity = response.EntityMetadata });
```

If you're after updating process name in grid of processes; it is:

```
var sec = new SetLocLabelsRequest
{
    AttributeName = "name",
    Labels = new LocalizedLabel[]
    {
        new LocalizedLabel
        {
            Label = "Thats not my name",
            LanguageCode = 1033
        }
    },
    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("workflow", 
        new Guid("3E8EBEE6-A2BC-4451-9C5F-B146B085413A"))
};
var res = (SetLocLabelsResponse)os.Execute(sec);
```

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setloclabelsrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.updateentityrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9